# Why TextBox changes its value only when a pause with Thread.sleep() it is used?

Tags: c#, textbox, updating

I have the code below that do some average operation to show the pending time for the processing to finish. Since in real
code, inside the while loop each iteration takes different times, the code below calculates the average.

The logic it works and only differs in several seconds only when larger files are processed, but the main issue I have
is that the textBox1 where I want to show the pending time is not being updated. It is showing always zero seconds and
the only way I found that texbox1 shows the pending time is adding adding a pause in the line "Thread.Sleep(1);" within
the "TextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{...})".

The problem with this is that is the file processed is larger it is taking many time to being processed because of the
addition of the Sleep(1).

Is there another way to update the TextBox1 without adding the sleep(1) pause?

You can test the code below with any file of 1MB or 2MB for example, adding a button named btnSelectFile, a button named 
btnRunProcess and a TextBox named TextBox1. Thanks for any help.

PS: The Array Times[] shows that not always the pending value is zero.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestTimer
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        string filename = "";
        long FileLength;
        FileInfo fInfo;
        Stopwatch sw1 =  new Stopwatch();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void BtnSelectFileClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Select file";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = ofd.FileName;
                fInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found");
                return;
            }           
        }   

        async void BtnRunProcessClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();            
            await Task.Run(() => Function1(filename, cts.Token), cts.Token);    
        }

    public void Function1(string inputfile, CancellationToken token)
    {
        int buffer = 1024;
        int IterationCounter = 0;
        int Iterations = 0;  
        double pendingTime = 0;           

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(inputfile, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            FileLength = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
            Iterations = (int)FileLength/buffer;                           
            byte[] chunk;   
            string[] Times = new string[Iterations + 2];

            sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew(); //Start time counter

            while (true)
            {                               
                chunk = reader.ReadBytes(buffer);

                if (chunk.Length == 0) {break;}

                foreach  (byte data in chunk)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(90/100); //Simulation of a task that takes some mili seconds
                }

                // pendingTime is the current average time-per-iteration,
                // times the number of iterations left
                double timePerIteration = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds/ ++IterationCounter;
                pendingTime = timePerIteration * (Iterations - IterationCounter);

                Times[IterationCounter] = string.Format("{0:0} s", pendingTime / 1000);

                TextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    // Let string.Format() take care of rounding for you
                    TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0} s", pendingTime / 1000);
                    //Thread.Sleep(1);
                });
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Execution time: " + string.Format("{0:0} s", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000) );
            MessageBox.Show(String.Join("-",Times),"Showing times for each iteration");
        }
    }               

    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, this `Thread.Sleep(90/100)` is identical to `Thread.Sleep(0)`.

Comment: Hi dymanoid. I didn't know. I was only trying to simulate a few miliseconds :).

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your code is interrupting the UI thread for each 1kb of data. This may simply be too fast. UI message queues are treated as priority queues, and the priority of "execute this arbitrary method" is always higher than the priority of "refresh the screen".

So, I'd recommend first factoring the "update the UI" portion out of your background code, using the `IProgress<T>` type provided for this purpose:

```
public void Function1(string inputfile, CancellationToken token, IProgress<double> progress)
{
  ...
      pendingTime = timePerIteration * (Iterations - IterationCounter);

      Times[IterationCounter] = string.Format("{0:0} s", pendingTime / 1000);

      if (progress != null)
        progress.Report(pendingTime);
  ...
}
```

Next, change your calling code so that it *throttles the updates* before bothering the UI thread. I have an [`ObservableProgress<T>` type in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d/cbac3fa2c85ef65752683a73fd0ebf262ba2144d) that uses Rx to do this in a simple way:

```
async void BtnRunProcessClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  using (var progress = ObservableProgress<double>.CreateForUi(value =>
    {
      TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0} s", pendingTime / 1000);
    }))
  {
    await Task.Run(() => Function1(filename, cts.Token), cts.Token, progress);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your help. I'm trying to use the solution you shared. I've added the ObservableProgress.cs to the Project and changed the code as you suggest but I get errors like "The type or namespace name 'Reactive' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234)". This happens for Reactive, ISubject and IScheduler.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. It still not updating the Texbox1, appears always as 0s. I've installed RX and added ObservableProgress.cs using  "Add  Existing item" as "Copy" to project  and  those errors dissapear. I changed the call to Function1 to "await Task.Run(() => Function1(filename, cts.Token, progress), cts.Token);" since I was getting errors.

Comment: @Sarmeu: If you're not seeing progress updates (no breakpoint is hit), try reducing the system under test.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I don't know what happens. I made the code smaller and remains showing only zero seconds in TexBox1. I did a test, if below the formula that gets the pendingTime, I set the pendingTime to a fix value, for example 249, the value is shown correctly in TextBox1.

Comment: @Sarmeu: Try `var timePerIteration = ((double)sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds) / ++IterationCounter;`

Comment: It happens the same Stephen with the formula you suggest, always shows zero. I did another test. If I generate pendingTime randomly the value is shown in textbox correctly. I mean adding "Random r = new Random();" and "pendingTime = r.Next(5, 15);" instead of "pendingTime = timePerIteration * (Iterations - IterationCounter);". It could be something with the formula?

Comment: @Sarmeu: Most likely.